# Split String in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String like this:

```
06%2F27%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C06%2F29%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C07%2F06%2F2012%2C07%2F19%2F2012%2C07%2F06%2F2012%2C07%2F19%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C07%2F20%2F2012%2C07%2F20%2F2012%2C07%2F27%2F2012%2C08%2F02%2F2012%2C07%2F20%2F2012%2C07%2F26%2F2012%2C08%2F03%2F2012%2C08%2F06%2F2012%2C08%2F06%2F2012%2C08%2F17%2F2012
```

I want it split it values like this:

```
%2F should be /

%2C marks the starting of new string
```

So values would be like:

06/27/2012 , 07/052012 etc

I tried creating somekind of regex for this, but did not succeed.

Example I tried:

```
String phrase = "06%2F27%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C06%2F29%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C07%2F06%2F2012%2C07%2F19%2F2012%2C07%2F06%2F2012%2C07%2F19%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C07%2F20%2F2012%2C07%2F20%2F2012%2C07%2F27%2F2012%2C08%2F02%2F2012%2C07%2F20%2F2012%2C07%2F26%2F2012%2C08%2F03%2F2012%2C08%2F06%2F2012%2C08%2F06%2F2012%2C08%2F17%2F2012";
String delims = "REGEX_GOES_HERE";
String[] tokens = phrase.split(delims);
```

Comment: I think you should first unescape the data, then process it.

Comment: Please include regex that you actually used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
String string = "06%2F27%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C06%2F29%2F2012"; // etc...
    String decoded = null;
    try {
        decoded = URLDecoder.decode(string, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] splitString = decoded.split(",");
    for (String i : splitString) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

If I understand it correctly, you're trying to split and replace with one operation. Don't.

If you accept that, then all you need is a [`URLDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) call that will replace `%..` sequences with the appropriate characters, followed by a simple `split()` with the string delimiter character.

Answer (score 2):

Your trouble is in charset, you must decode it.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] tokens = phrase.replaceAll("%2F","/").split("%2C");
```

Answer (score 0):

A lazy way is to replace all your String by the values you need :

```
String toModify = "06%2F27%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C06%2F29%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C07%2F06%2F2012%2C07%2F19%2F2012%2C07%2F06%2F2012%2C07%2F19%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C07%2F05%2F2012%2C07%2F20%2F2012%2C07%2F20%2F2012%2C07%2F27%2F2012%2C08%2F02%2F2012%2C07%2F20%2F2012%2C07%2F26%2F2012%2C08%2F03%2F2012%2C08%2F06%2F2012%2C08%2F06%2F2012%2C08%2F17%2F2012"
String my result = toModify.replaceAll("%2F","/").replaceAll("%2C"," ").replaceAll.... ;
```